# Moderated mediation has different results if run on R (rosetta) or on SPSS (PROCESS)?

Tags: r, interaction, spss, mediation

I run the same moderated mediation in spss and in R.

In R I run

```
library(rosetta) 
output <- gemm(dat = db2, 
                xvar  = "Independent", 
                mvars = "Mediator",  
                yvar  = "Dependent",
                xmmod = "XM moderator", 
                nboot = 1000); 
print(output)
```

In SPSS, with Process 3.5, I run

```
PROCESS 
y=Dependent
/x=Independent  
/m=Mediator
/w=XM moderator
  /contrast=1
  /plot=1
  /decimals=F10.4
  /jn=1
  /center=1
  /moments=1
  /effsize=1
  /stand=1 
  /boot=1000
  /xmtest=1 
  /conf=95
  /longname=1
  /model=7.
```

The two set of results that I get are very different. In R the overall moderated mediation seems to be significant, while in PROCESS the moderation is not significant at all. R2 and estimatea are overall very different.

I tried to test a more simple analysis (only the mediation) and the results are the same in both software (significant in both cases).
Any idea of why this is happening?
I tried to install processR on R in order to try to run the analysis in the two version of Process (on R and or SPSS), but it seems like it is not available yet.

Here are the outputs from the two softwares

R rosetta

```
The dependent variable is:    Dependent

The predictor variable is:      Independent

The model contains 1 mediators: Mediator

The moderators for the x-m path(s): Moderator

No moderators for the m-y path(s)

No covariates for the mediators

No covariates for the dependent variable

​

​

Explained variance (R-square) of the mediators and dependent variable:

​

--------------------

Dependent         R2

------------ -------

Mediator     0.879

​

Dependent     0.038

--------------------

​

​

​

Estimate of total effect

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

effect                          est      se       t   pvalue   ci.lower   ci.upper

---------------------------- ------ ------- ------- -------- ---------- ----------

intercept                      3.73   0.134   27.90    0.000      3.468       3.99

​

Independent --> Dependent     0.12   0.036    3.27    0.001      0.047       0.19

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

​

​

​

Estimates of a-paths

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

path                                  est      se        z   pvalue   ci.lower

-------------------------------- -------- ------- -------- -------- ----------

Independent --> Mediator          0.044   0.012     3.55     0.00      0.021

​

Moderator --> Mediator     -0.437   0.016   -27.64     0.00     -0.468

​

Independent x Moderator       0.197   0.004    45.96     0.00      0.189

--> Mediator

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Dependent

Table: Table continues below

​

----------

ci.upper

----------

0.069

​

-0.406

​

0.206

----------

​

​

​

Estimates of b-paths

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

path                           est      se      z   pvalue   ci.lower   ci.upper

--------------------------- ------ ------- ------ -------- ---------- ----------

Mediator --> Dependent     0.14   0.048   2.83    0.005      0.043       0.22

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

​

​

​

Direct effect (c')

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

path                             est      se      z   pvalue   ci.lower   ci.upper

---------------------------- ------- ------- ------ -------- ---------- ----------

Independent --> Dependent     0.086   0.038   2.24    0.025      0.012       0.16

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

​

​

​

Indirect effects (a*b)

------------------------------------------------------------------

through          est      se      z   pvalue   ci.lower   ci.upper

------------ ------- ------- ------ -------- ---------- ----------

Mediator     0.006   0.003   2.10    0.036      0.002      0.012

​

total          0.006   0.003   2.10    0.036      0.002      0.012

------------------------------------------------------------------

​

​

​

Completely standardized effect sizes

------------------------------------------------------------------

through          est      se      z   pvalue   ci.lower   ci.upper

------------ ------- ------- ------ -------- ---------- ----------

Mediator     0.008   0.003   2.23    0.026      0.001      0.014

​

total          0.008   0.003   2.23    0.026      0.001      0.014

------------------------------------------------------------------

​

​

​

Ratio (indirect to total) based effect sizes

------------------------------------------------------------------

through          est     se       z   pvalue   ci.lower   ci.upper

------------ ------- ------ ------- -------- ---------- ----------

Mediator     0.066   4.41   0.015     0.99      0.013       0.28

​

total          0.066   4.41   0.015     0.99      0.013       0.28

------------------------------------------------------------------

​
```

​

Process 3.5 (model 7)

```
Run MATRIX procedure: 
 
***************** PROCESS Procedure for SPSS Version 3.5 ***************** 
 
          Written by Andrew F. Hayes, Ph.D.       www.afhayes.com 
    Documentation available in Hayes (2018). www.guilford.com/p/hayes3 
 
************************************************************************** 
Model  : 7 
    Y  : Dependent 
    X  : Independent 
    M  : Mediator 
    W  : Moderator 
 
Sample 
Size:  478 
 
************************************************************************** 
OUTCOME VARIABLE: 
 Mediator 
 
Model Summary 
          R       R-sq        MSE          F        df1        df2          p 
      ,3039      ,0923      ,7242    16,0731     3,0000   474,0000      ,0000 
 
Model 
              coeff         se          t          p       LLCI       ULCI 
constant     2,3133      ,0390    59,3309      ,0000     2,2366     2,3899 
Independent      ,2251      ,0338     6,6599      ,0000      ,1587      ,2915 
Moderator      ,0193      ,0254      ,7589      ,4483     -,0306      ,0691 
Int_1        -,0320      ,0211    -1,5141      ,1307     -,0735      ,0095 
 
Product terms key: 
 Int_1    :        Independent x        Moderator 
 
Test(s) of highest order unconditional interaction(s): 
       R2-chng          F        df1        df2          p 
X*W      ,0044     2,2925     1,0000   474,0000      ,1307 
---------- 
    Focal predict: Independent (X) 
          Mod var: Moderator (W) 
 
Data for visualizing the conditional effect of the focal predictor: 
Paste text below into a SPSS syntax window and execute to produce plot. 
 
DATA LIST FREE/ 
   Independent   Moderator   Mediator   . 
BEGIN DATA. 
    -1,1550    -1,5392     1,9668 
      ,0000    -1,5392     2,2836 
     1,1550    -1,5392     2,6005 
    -1,1550      ,0000     2,0533 
      ,0000      ,0000     2,3133 
     1,1550      ,0000     2,5732 
    -1,1550     1,5392     2,1398 
      ,0000     1,5392     2,3429 
     1,1550     1,5392     2,5460 
END DATA. 
GRAPH/SCATTERPLOT= 
 Independent WITH     Mediator BY       Moderator . 
 
************************************************************************** 
OUTCOME VARIABLE: 
 Dependent 
 
Model Summary 
          R       R-sq        MSE          F        df1        df2          p 
      ,1961      ,0384      ,8014     9,4948     2,0000   475,0000      ,0001 
 
Model 
              coeff         se          t          p       LLCI       ULCI 
constant     3,8302      ,1186    32,3073      ,0000     3,5972     4,0632 
Independent      ,0859      ,0371     2,3126      ,0212      ,0129      ,1588 
Mediator      ,1372      ,0482     2,8486      ,0046      ,0426      ,2319 
 
Test(s) of X by M interaction: 
          F        df1        df2          p 
      ,1709     1,0000   474,0000      ,6795 
 
****************** DIRECT AND INDIRECT EFFECTS OF X ON Y ***************** 
 
Direct effect of X on Y 
     Effect         se          t          p       LLCI       ULCI 
      ,0859      ,0371     2,3126      ,0212      ,0129      ,1588 
 
Conditional indirect effects of X on Y: 
 
INDIRECT EFFECT: 
 Independent    ->    Mediator    ->    Dependent 
 
   Moderator     Effect     BootSE   BootLLCI   BootULCI 
    -1,5392      ,0376      ,0152      ,0109      ,0711 
      ,0000      ,0309      ,0122      ,0090      ,0568 
     1,5392      ,0241      ,0111      ,0054      ,0489 
 
      Index of moderated mediation: 
              Index     BootSE   BootLLCI   BootULCI 
Moderator     -,0044      ,0036     -,0127      ,0014 
--- 
 
*********************** ANALYSIS NOTES AND ERRORS ************************ 
 
Level of confidence for all confidence intervals in output: 
  95,0000 
 
Number of bootstrap samples for percentile bootstrap confidence intervals: 
  5000 
 
W values in conditional tables are the mean and +/- SD from the mean. 
 
NOTE: The following variables were mean centered prior to analysis: 
          Moderator Independent 
 
NOTE: Standardized coefficients not available for models with moderators. 
 
WARNING: Variables names longer than eight characters can produce incorrect output 
when some variables in the data file have the same first eight characters. Shorter 
variable names are recommended. By using this output, you are accepting all risk 
and consequences of interpreting or reporting results that may be incorrect. 
 
------ END MATRIX -----
```